# Does the speed of Green Lanterns depend on their willpower, or do they have a top speed they can fly?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

According to the Green Lantern wikia,

> A Green Lantern can create any particular items or construct that they
> can imagine as long as they have the willpower necessary to will it
> into existence. The constructs are made out of bright green energy,
> which is a tangible form of pure willpower, and they exist only as
> long as a Green Lantern is fueling it with their willpower. Items
> created by the rings are not indestructible and are only as powerful
> as the willpower of the Green Lantern creating them.

[Green Lantern Ring powers](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Ring#Powers)

How about their speed?
Does the speed of Green Lanterns depend on their willpower, or do they have a top speed they can fly?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-fast-can-a-Green-Lantern-fly